Disagreement with closed question
I am interested about this recent closed question. I thought I'd ask here because I clearly have a different opinion to some, and I wanted to discuss the reasoning.
The question is marked as closed for "unclear what you're asking", which I just don't think it is - as per Hunter's prompt I've provided an answer in the comments.
I realize it doesn't necessarily show large amounts of prior research, but that doesn't make it unclear. These terms are used as key 'selling points' for a number of schemes, including many of the CAESAR submissions. Some examples using the terms specifically are given below - most of which are from CAESER because I have the zoo in-front of me:

"Online": OCB, Ascon, CBA, APE, NORX
"memory-constrained devices": Ketje / Keyak / Spongewrap, 
"lightweight": PRESENT, JAMBO, APE, BLINKER (presented CT-RSA14)

eCrypt report on Lightweight crypto

tl;dr: This question might not be the best ever written, but it is clear so at least we should close it with an appropriate reason.

I've certainly seen worse questions than that. Also, the “lack of research” can indeed be argued about. After all, OP shows he/she is still learning but already able to clearly define the (let's just call it) “point of confusion”. I'm not convinced a search engine quest would be able to simply spit out really satisfying answers to the question… which makes Crypto.SE a good place to ask. That's what we're here for, aren't we? ;) Keeping it short: I agree with your disagreement and voted to reopen it accordingly.

The question has now been re-opened.
